# Selectize js value

Tags: php, jquery

My results from Selectize js return the following `["0005","0006"]`

These represent gift codes that can be chosen by an user. I want to execute a php statement for each given code instead of what I am getting now.

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE gifts SET gift_status="0" WHERE gift_id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $gift_id);
```

I don't know what is `$gift_id` for each given result gift status 0 = Gift not available

How can I do this? Please help!

Comment: post your code part that you tried.

Comment: have you included the selectize scripts and stylesheet properly?

Comment: yes, i want to know how to execute php script for each given gift_code

Comment: when a user selects 0005, what should get updated?

Comment: i want to update gift Which has the code 0005

Comment: but if user will choose gifts ex. 0005, 0006 i want to update two gift